# ListView.builder in flutter calling itemBuilder unnecessarily

Tags: flutter

I have a doubt about ListView.builder().
I am developing an application, and there are some lists with sublists, but I couldn't understand a behavior in these cases.
I thought this behavior just happened in my app, but I tried simulating it in a new app and it happened too.
In this case, I have the first ListView and when I scroll him, it always calls the item builder. Okay, I got it, and it happened because the ListView.builder() works on demand (lazily mode), but if I open another ListView.builder() in another Scaffold() and I close the keyboard opened by TextFieldForm, the itemBuilder of the first ListView is called... I didn't understand this behavior and I want to know if this behavior is correct.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40151305/167963586-3aac6624-3c9e-4f21-88f4-5c586206c49e.mp4

Guys, it is a video example app, but in my oficial app, it is called the backend endpoints, the ListView needs to load some widgets but it's hidden, I don't see that need. I have tried use the cacheExtent property, and other properties in the documentation, but it happens too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

List<String> valuesListViewOne = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17'];
List<String> valuesListViewTwo = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MainWidget(),
      routes: {
        'callListViewOne': (_) => const ListViewOne(),
        'callListViewTwo': (_) => const ListViewTwo(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main view'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 35,
          color: Colors.black,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('callListViewOne'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListViewOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('List View One'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(),
            const Divider(),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: valuesListViewOne.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        valuesListViewOne[idx],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 35,
          color: Colors.black,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('callListViewTwo'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListViewTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('List View Two'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(),
            const Divider(),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: valuesListViewTwo.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        valuesListViewTwo[idx],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I find this video a bit confusing. Both showing numbers and the same background color.

Comment: I am able to replicate the same in the latest stable version of flutter. I came to a conclusion that the page one will still be there in behind the page two. And when the keyboard is closed, the size changes which calls the itemBuilder as it is designed to.

Comment: yeah, i thought the same thing, but is it correctly? or is there a workaround to not execute the size changes on pages hidden?